# Is there any way to profile or debug remote event receivers on SharePoint 2013 Online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I have registered a Remote Event Receiver using the SharePoint CSOM, by configuring a `EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation` object and adding it to a list. I can use Powershell (again with the CSOM) to determine that the Remote Event Receiver is configured for the list, and that the `ReceiverUrl` is correct.

However, when I perform an action that should trigger the Remote Event Receiver, nothing is happening. I have ensured that the Remote Event Receiver endpoint (ReceiverUrl) is visible outside of my network, and have also confirmed that there is currently no traffic reaching the machine from SharePoint online.

Is there any way to debug this communication issue from SharePoint Online, to determine if:

- The Remote Event Receiver is firing
- A connection attempt is being made
- Any errors are occurring

I'm at a loss as far as what the next step should be. This process works fine on a SharePoint 2013 local installation. I don't understand how Microsoft can release this product with no means of debugging or viewing log files.

Comment: On Msdn there is an article on remote debugging http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/03/21/update-to-debugging-sharepoint-2013-remote-events-using-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't apply to my situation.

This is a remote event receiver configured via CSOM, not an installed "app."